# First time using an image map

Tags: html, css, image, imagemap

I'm attempting to put an image map on the picture of this guitar so I can point out vital points on the guitar. In my first attempt I'm trying to put the coordinate points around the whammy bar of the guitar (a whammy bar is the stick jutting out on the base of the guitar). I know I'm doing something wrong because I can't click on the whammy bar to take me to the indicated url. What's the problem?

```css
/* 
   Image Map Independent Project 
   Filename: styles.css

   Author:   Justus Self
   Date:     3/2/17
   HTML5 and CSS3 Illustrated Unit G, Independent Project
 */
 
/* reset styles */
html {
   font-size: 14px;
}
article, aside, body, div, footer, header, h1, h2, h3, nav, p, img {
   border: 0;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
}

/* body and page container */
body {
   background-color: black;
}
.container {
   max-width: 960px;
   margin: auto;
}

/* header section */
header {
   padding: 1em 2% 0.5em;
   text-align: center;
   background-color: rgb(139,0,0);
   overflow: auto;
   color: white;
}
h1{
   font-size: 2.4em;
   line-height: 1.4em;
   font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}

/* main content */
article div{
   padding: 4em 3%;
   width: 65%;
   position: relative;
   left: 15%;
}
article p {
 color: white;
 padding: .1em 4em 5em 0;
 text-align: center;
 left: 10%;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 15px;
}
article h2 {
 padding: 1em;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
}

/* footer section */
footer {
   font-size: 16px;
   padding: .5em;
   color: white;
   background-color: rgb(139,0,0);
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title> Guitar Anatomy </title>
      <!--
         Image Map Independent Project
         Filename: index.html
      
         Author: Justus Self  
         Date:     3/2/17
         HTML5 and CSS3 Illustrated Unit G, Independent Project 
      -->
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <script src="modernizr.custom.40753.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
   </head>
   <body>
 <div class="container">
  <header>
   <h1> The Different Parts of a Guitar </h1>
  </header>
  <article>
   <h2> Learning The Basics </h2>
   <div>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/kKVxRrO.png" alt="image map of a guitar" width="700" height="250" usemap="#guitar">
    <map name="guitar"> 
    <area href="http://www.hearandplay.com/main/the-purpose-of-the-whammy-bar" alt="hearandplay" 
    target="_blank" shape= poly coords="133,222,265,232,189,213,196,244">
    </map>
   </div>
  <p> This is what a standard electric/acoustic guitar looks like, click on the tags in the image to learn more about their specific parts. </p>
  </article>
  <footer>
            <p> Sarcoxie, MO 64862 &bull; (417) 353-9591</p>
         </footer>
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Give us a working demo please.

Comment: What do you mean working demo? You mean a demo of a working image map?

Comment: Did you look at the code you shared with us? The image of the guitar doesn't work. How are we supposed to help identify why a part of the image isn't clickable if we can't see the image?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. It's because it's a local image on my pc. How can I make it so that you can see it?

Comment: Host it somewhere, either a personal server or an image sharing service like imgur, and reference the public URL in the image `src`

Comment: Okay I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the poly coordinates were off and the width/height you specified doesn't match the aspect ratio of the image. My guess is you wrote the coords based on the image's native width/height, not the re-sized (scaled down) size you've specified in the HTML.

Resized the source image to match the width you specified in your code, then re-established the poly coords. Also you have a space in the `shape= poly` attribute.

```html
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/t3VMpIS.png" alt="image map of a guitar" width="700" height="284" usemap="#guitar">
<map name="guitar">
  <area href="http://www.hearandplay.com/main/the-purpose-of-the-whammy-bar" alt="hearandplay" target="_blank" shape="poly" coords="98,156,127,170,194,163,199,176,131,185,87,175">
</map>
```

Comment: Michael to the rescue again. Thanks so much.

Comment: @SkryBlackfall no sweat!

Comment: @SkryBlackfall I'm curious, did you establish the coords from the native image size? Or did you re-size it to 700x250 and establish the coords based off of that dimension? It's worth noting that if the image size changes for any reason (like responsiveness) the coords will need to be re-done. Making the height/width 700x250 also distorts the image, because if you size the original width down to 700, the height that matches the native aspect ratio would be 283px, not 250px.

Comment: I used Paint to get the coordinates after I resized the image in my html. So what probably happened is I resized it in the code and it made the coordinates completely different when I opened the full size image in Paint. Just a very silly mistake on my part.

Comment: @SkryBlackfall yup, that's it. Cool, glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

**Your `<area>` (and the link) is working, your coords are just in the wrong place.**

You'll notice that, in your snippet, if you hover slowly along the bottom of the guitar body, your cursor will at times become a pointer. This is where your mapped area currently is. Try these coords for better results:

```
100,125,100,150,196,143,201,148,196,153,125,168,87,155
```

Comment: I guess I'm going to have to learn how to get the coordinates properly. Your solution also works, thank you very much.